# Sync Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, synchronization

I need  function that is called several times in different locations is synchronous, getItemsCampanha and onQuerySucceeded, example:

```
function getItemsCampanha(CAML) {            
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

$(document).ready(function () {        
     $('#Div').change(function () {
         if ($('#Select').val() == "Value") {            
             getItemsCampanha(CAML);
             alert("2");
         }
     });
 });

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("1");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
}
```

I need the alert respect the numbers 1, 2. But alert 2, 1.

Comment: You got to use a callback, the only way it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your goal really is, but what about...

```
 function getItemsCampanha(CAML) {
     context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
         Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Div').change(function () {
         funToCallAfterQuerySucceeds = function() {
             if ($('#Select').val() == "Value") {
                 getItemsCampanha(CAML);
                 alert("2");
             }
         }
     });
 });

 function onQuerySucceeded() {
     alert("1");
     funToCallAfterQuerySucceeds();
 }
```